# Функция, которая ищет необходимые символы в строках?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, анализ-данных

Необходимо, чтобы, где в коментарие было слово в скобках "(удален)", "(удалил товар)" и т.д., брались, либо все 3 строки с данными, либо строка где адрес, дата, номер (лучше так).

Данo:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame({'№':['1', 'NaN', 'NaN', '2','NaN', 'NaN'],

'Дата':['2020-06-03', 'NaN', 'NaN', '2020-06-05', 'NaN', 'NaN'],

'Адрес':['Delhi', 'NaN', 'NaN', 'Kannauj', 'NaN', 'NaN'],

'Остальное':['Цена', 'Остаток', 'Комментарий','Цена', 'Остаток', 'Комментарий']

'Список1':['0', '0', '(удалено)','0', '1','(выкладка)']} 

pat = r"(?:удален)"
mask = data.iloc[:, 4].str.contains(pat)
```

Выводит:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-111-42532444bc05> in <module>()
----> 1 data[mask]

1 frames

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/common.py in is_bool_indexer(key)
    134                 na_msg = "Cannot mask with non-boolean array containing NA / NaN values"
    135                 if isna(key).any():
--> 136                     raise ValueError(na_msg)
    137                 return False
    138             return True

ValueError: Cannot mask with non-boolean array containing NA / NaN values
```

Желаемый результат:

```
data_delete = pd.DataFrame({'№':['1', 'NaN', 'NaN' ],

'Дата':['2020-06-03', 'NaN', 'NaN'],

'Адрес':['Delhi', 'NaN', 'NaN'],

'Остальное':['Цена', 'Остаток', 'Комментарий']

'Список1':['0', '0', '(удалено)']} 

data_other = pd.DataFrame({'№':['2','NaN', 'NaN'],

'Дата':[ '2020-06-05', 'NaN', 'NaN'],

'Адрес':['Kannauj', 'NaN', 'NaN'],

'Остальное':['Цена', 'Остаток', 'Комментарий']

'Список1':['0', '1','(выкладка)']}
```

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 3):

попробуйте так:

```
pat = r"(?:удален)"
mask = data.iloc[:, 3].str.contains(pat)

delete = data[mask]    
other = data[~mask]
```

---

результат:

```
In [105]: delete
Out[105]:
  Пользователь   Товар   Адрес     Комментарии
0         Катя   кефир   Delhi  (товар удален)
1         Саша  молоко  Kanpur       (удалено)

In [106]: other
Out[106]:
  Пользователь    Товар      Адрес Комментарии
2         Маша   творог  Allahabad      (фото)
3         Петя  колбаса    Kannauj  (выкладка)
```

Comment: что делать, если выдает такую ошибку, хотя я пробовал пустоты заполнять другим текстом? ValueError: Cannot mask with non-boolean array containing NA / NaN values

Comment: @АндрейАлександрович, можете привести в вопросе __воспроизводимый__ пример данных?

Comment: Еще раз прошу прощения, не привык, исправил.

Comment: @АндрейАлександрович, у меня не получается воспроизвести ошибку с вашим примером данных. Кроме этого теперь стало непонятно по какому критерию вы хотите разделить данные

Comment: на самом деле, я взял на отдельном фрейме и все работает как часы, ваш метод, благодарю! но именно на моей базе выдает такую ошибку. Как считаете, возможно ли это сервисные символы мешают или что может способствовать такой ошибке?

Comment: @АндрейАлександрович, для того, чтобы иметь возможность помочь вам, нам нужен __воспроизводимый__ пример данных. Как вы уже сами заметили, ответы пишутся и проверяются на указанных в вопросе примерах.